# Prove that $w = u + v$ is a solution to $Ax = 2b$ if $v$ and $u$ are solutions to $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v$ and $u$ be solutions to $Ax = b$.

Prove that $w = u + v$ is a solution to $Ax = 2b$

I'm pretty confused on how to solve this. Am I able to assume that or prove somehow that $v$ and $u$ have the same $b$ value? Or is there a more general assumption I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just evaluate Aw
Aw=A(u+v)=Au+Av=b+b=2b

Comment: oh >.< I was just over thinking it with all the theorems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You know that $Au=b$ and the same for $v$.  So evaluate $Aw=A(u+v)$